# Laplace Inversion using the Residue Theorem

Tags: residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

**UPDATE: I've attempted to answer this question**

I'm trying to invert a Laplace Transform using Cauchy's Residue Theorem. The transform is

$$\Theta(s)=\frac{F(s)}{G(s)}$$

where

$$
F(s)=[1+\gamma P(s)] [As^{-1}+\theta(0)]
$$

and
$$
G(s)=[1+\gamma P(s)] (s+A) + \gamma BP(s)
$$

in which $\theta(0)$ is the initial condition of the inverse transform function in the time domain, $\gamma$, $A$, and $B$ are real constants, and $P(s)$ is given by the series

$$
P(s)=s\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} \frac{C_k}{s+\lambda_k^2}
$$

where $N \ge 50$. The  terms $C_k$ and $\lambda_k$ are the real Fourier-Bessel coefficients and real eigenvalues that are the outcome of another coupled problem.

**Here is the approach that I used:**

There is one pole at $s=0$ and the remaining $N$ poles $z_k, k=1\cdots N$ are the zeroes of $G(s)$, all of which lie on the negative Real Axis, and each of which I have calculated with residuals pretty close to machine roundoff. Following the Residue Theorem, the Inverse Laplace Transform can be written as

$$
\theta(t)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=N}e^{z_k t}F(z_k) \lim_{s\to z_k}\frac{s-z_k}{G(s)}
$$

whereupon the indeterminate limit can be resolved with L'Hôpital's Rule yielding

$$
\theta(t)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} e^{z_k t}\frac{F(z_k)}{G'(s)}
$$

where $G'(s)$ is the derivative w.r.t. $s$ of $G(s)$

$$
G'(s)=[1+\gamma P(s)] +\gamma (s+A+B)P'(s)
$$

and $P'(s)$ is the derivative w.r.t. $s$ of $P(s)$

$$
P'(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} \frac{C_k}{s+\lambda_k^2}-s\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} \frac{C_k}{(s+\lambda_k^2)^2}
$$

**Issues:**

I've observed that the evaluation of $\theta(t)$ doesn't seem quite right especially for small times and in particular for larger values of $\gamma$. Moreover, it demonstrates a sensitivity to the eigenvalues and Coefficients $C_k$ that is not consistent with expected observations. Rather than inundate the reader with more details at this stage, I'll be glad to update the question with more relevant information following any comments.

**My specific questions:**

Is the approach that I've used with the Residue Theorem fundamentally correct?   Is there anything else that I should be aware of when solving problems of the type above?

Many thanks, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe incorporating a pre-processing to reduce the transfer function to its simplest expression, make the inversion process more accurate. For  $N = 2$, the final transfer function is presented, adequate to apply the method

$$
\Theta(s) = \frac{A \left(C_1 \gamma  s \left(\lambda _2^2+s\right)+\left(\lambda _1^2+s\right) \left(C_2 \gamma  s+\lambda _2^2+s\right)\right)}{s \left(C_1
   \gamma  s \left(\lambda _2^2+s\right) (A+B+s)+\left(\lambda _1^2+s\right) \left(C_2 \gamma  s (A+B+s)+(A+s) \left(\lambda
   _2^2+s\right)\right)\right)}
$$

with denominator coeficients

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 A \lambda _1^2 \lambda _2^2 \\
 \left(\lambda _2^2+A+(A+B) \gamma  C_2\right) \lambda _1^2+\left(A+(A+B) \gamma  C_1\right) \lambda _2^2 \\
 \lambda _1^2+\lambda _2^2+A+\gamma  C_2 \left(\lambda _1^2+A+B\right)+\gamma  C_1 \left(\lambda _2^2+A+B\right) \\
 \gamma  \left(C_1+C_2\right)+1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Follow a symbolic processing script in MATHEMATICA to implement this simplification

```
P[s_, n_] := s Sum[Subscript[C, k]/(s + Subscript[lambda, k]^2), {k, 1, n}]
F[s_, n_] := (1 + gamma P[s, n]) A/s
G[s_, n_] := (1 + gamma P[s, n]) (s + A) + gamma B P[s, n]
Phi[s_, n_] := F[s, n]/G[s, n]

n = 2;
Phisn = Phi[s, n] // Together
num = Phisn // Numerator;
den = Phisn // Denominator;
Phis0 = num/den // FullSimplify
den0 = Phis0 // Denominator
```

Attached a python script to obtain the inverse Laplace transform from a transfer function $G(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)}$ with the $N(s) = a_n s^n + \cdots + a_0$ and $D(s) = b_m s^m+\cdots b_0$ The $N$ coefficients are given in num and the $D$ coefficients in den both in power decreasing style. $G(s)$ is assumed strictly proper. The script gives a sequence of response terms which should be added to compound the time inversion.

```
import scipy.signal as R 


num = [6.92462, 73.8839, 400.845, 1455.68, 3946.03, 8455.99, \
       14824.9, 21736.1, 27038.6, 28803.0, 26421.5, 20924.8, \
       14306.8, 8423.79, 4249.23, 1821.19, 655.104, 194.266, \
       46.253, 8.49133, 1.12494, 0.0951142, 0.00380817]
den = [1, 10.9544, 61.0185, 227.587, 634.139, 1398.5, 2527.38,\
       3827.46, 4929.55, 5452.66, 5212.0, 4320.11, 3108.84, 1940.74,\
       1048.1, 487.221, 193.437, 64.822, 18.0145, 4.04279, 0.702988, \
       0.0884995, 0.00711991, 0.000271338, 0]

#num = [3, 2, 2]
#den = [5, 2, 2, 1]

(r,p,k) = R.residue(num,den,tol=1e-5)

toler1 = 1e-5
toler2 = 1e-15
i      = 0
j      = 1

while i < len(r):
    alphai = real(r[i])
    betai  = imag(r[i])
    gammai = real(p[i])
    deltai = imag(p[i])

    if abs(betai) > toler1:
        if abs(alphai) < toler2:
            alphai = 0   
        print("{4} >>> 2*exp({0}*t)*({1}*cos({2}*t) + {3}*sin({2}*t))".format(gammai,alphai,deltai,-betai,j))
        i += 2
    else:
        if abs(gammai) > toler2:
            print("{2} >>> {0}*exp({1}*t)".format(1*alphai,1*gammai,j))
        else:
            print("{1} >>> {0}".format(1*alphai,j))
        i += 1
    j += 1
```

The inversion problem gives as result

```
1 >>> 14.0347831855
2 >>> -0.483039070616*exp(-0.187218948148*t)
3 >>> 2*exp(-0.309980077984*t)*(-1.97460596883*cos(-0.0673684262979*t)+0.0408608048522*sin(-0.0673684262979*t))
4 >>> 2*exp(-0.317487772418*t)*(-0.853151294864*cos(-0.193564461065*t)+0.11474944314*sin(-0.193564461065*t))
5 >>> 2*exp(-0.262710062176*t)*(-0.192942085124*cos(-0.380624549122*t)+-0.196136519663*sin(-0.380624549122*t))
6 >>> 2*exp(-0.0566781486718*t)*(-2.04346564851*cos(-0.473314360884*t)+-0.784055678847*sin(-0.473314360884*t))
7 >>> 2*exp(-0.253402873944*t)*(-0.224610305483*cos(-0.602941037526*t)+0.573864761592*sin(-0.602941037526*t))
8 >>> 2*exp(-0.18001778095*t)*(-0.214405624466*cos(-0.953393232567*t)+-0.105678203189*sin(-0.953393232567*t))
9 >>> 2*exp(-0.25943110475*t)*(-0.377299755441*cos(-1.02160634165*t)+-0.266212072126*sin(-1.02160634165*t))
10 >>> 2*exp(-1.07768853278*t)*(0.0995875511961*cos(-0.120122202754*t)+-0.456124154697*sin(-0.120122202754*t))
11 >>> 2*exp(-0.674142284507*t)*(-0.207698716256*cos(-1.01903055486*t)+-0.0654651577739*sin(-1.01903055486*t))
12 >>> 2*exp(-1.08508395079*t)*(-0.222022363057*cos(-0.651792664191*t)+-0.740528774445*sin(-0.651792664191*t))
13 >>> 2*exp(-0.906967936955*t)*(-0.565257846658*cos(-0.938474102998*t)+-0.35832504633*sin(-0.938474102998*t))
```

That should be added to give the response to an impulse. In the figure are shown two curves. One the assumed exact and the other, the computed by the script.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo. My problem is that I have at minimum $N=50$. Moreover, I need an Excel implementation and don't have access to Mathematica. However, your answer gave me an idea as to whether I could look into some sort of factorisation. It doesn't seem obvious, but perhaps worth a look. Thanks again.

Comment: ANother question: Is the Method of Residues known to cause numerical artifacts due to poor factorisation or the lack thereof altogether?

Comment: With polynomials of such a high degree, I think that it would be more appropriate to use an inversion method that approximates the transfer function globally, such as those inversion methods using the orthogonal polynomials of Laguerre.

Comment: Do the Laguerre polynomials offer a specific advantage over, say - a Laurent Series expansion?

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar As long as you use the Excel for  calculations, I offer a python script to do the same. I hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! The parameters that I used are A=200, B=10, $\gamma$=0.1, $N=50$. The Eigenvalues are strictly increasing and the Fourier-Bessel coefficients are strictly decreasing. Both are functions of a parameter called the *Drainage Radius*. I can send you the values in a spreadsheet, if you would like to indulge me by cross-checking the solution that I have. Also, what did you think of my answer (which raises another question!)

Comment: Please. Send me the spreadsheet containing the parameter values. I will send you my results after calculation. I saw your answer and I celebrated that the question was resolved.

Comment: Thanks again @Cesareo. I didn't see a contact link in your profile? Is there another way or a repository for sharing information on Stack Exchange? Btw, I added a graphic showing the transient response of $\theta$ compared to a function-sampling algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the cause of the discrepancy. The solution of the underlying problem in the time domain is

$$
\theta(t)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} e^{z_k t}\frac{F(z_k)}{G'(s)}
$$

as written above. The problem is that at time $0$, the initial condition $\theta(0))$ must be  honoured. This requires that 
$$
\theta(0)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{k=N} \frac{F(z_k)}{G'(s)}
$$

which is violated by a small amount whose precise magnitude depends on how large the values of the first few poles are. I found that if I added this difference to the solution, everything works perfectly. See the figure below. The Gaver-Stehfest approach uses a function sampling algorithm and is well suited for diffusion problems.

[image]

What I *still* don't get is even though I've actually included $\theta(0)$ in the expression for $F(s)$, this isn't satisfied in what is I believe a definite integral evaluation in the Method of residues. What gives?!